# How to fix authorization denied in a roblox api request! [Node.js] [Roblox]

Tags: node.js, roblox

so I need to code something for my parents, that blocks my brother from playing inappropriate games!
But I cant even request what hes playing through the roblox presence api (https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users) I keep on getting the following error

```
  errors: [
    {
      code: 0,
      message: 'Authorization has been denied for this request.'
    }
  ]
}
```

The Code Im Using Is

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

fetch("https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users", {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': fetch.headers,
  Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Cookie: ".ROLOSECURITY=_|[RobloxSecurityCodeHere]",
},
body: "{  \n   \"userIds\": [ \\ \n     616975163 \\ \n   ] \\ \n }"
  })
.then(res => {
  return res.json()
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.log('Error Retying!'))
```

I'd like to know how to fix this error without using a proxy!
please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is for a game then enable studio access to api services

Comment: its not for a game though

Comment: i have an easy fix to your problem roblox does not allow inappropriate content as long as the account age is set under 13

Comment: you can also find api help on the roblox developer page

Comment: you could make it so if he plays roblox on browser abort connection if the content is inappropriate

Comment: just saying i don't really recommend javascript for roblox

Comment: i recommend using something like python or something else

Comment: Thank you, This is really helpful information! I will stick to Javascript though!

Comment: But how exactly would one abort connections with node.js? Please tell me, Id like to Know!